# FAILED TO CONNECT TO /127.0.0.1:443 - ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: java, android, android-studio, localhost, ip

i have this kind of problem when i try to run my app project in android studio it keeps give me an error "**failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:443**". im using local ip for that. but when i try using 192.168.1.10 or 10.0.2.2 it doesn't work too.

this is my retro code

```
public class RetroServer {
private static final String baseURL = "https://127.0.0.1/laundry/";
private static Retrofit retro;
public static Retrofit konekRetrofit(){
    if(retro == null){
        retro = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retro;
}
```

in my retro code there's 2 of this symbols }}

and this is my androidmanifest.xml code

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Laundry">
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        tools:ignore="MissingClass">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

if you guys can help me with this problem, thank you so much

Comment: `try to run my app project in android studio` ? What are you doing? I would rather think you would try to run your Android app on an Android phone. Pretty unclear.

Comment: i have to run the app on android studio emulator because this app for my final exam and i have to present it later

Comment: Please remove the `android-studio` tag. And tell in your post that you use an emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do simple test in your emulator.
From your emulator.
Can you open your browser. After that, open your URL. (10.0.2.2)
If everything good.
Then you need to setup network_config in your android manifest.
Please check https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain>
    </domain-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false" />
</network-security-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete della answer : after you make the test successful, create a new **xml** file in the **res** section. Replace the code inside with della's one. Then add to your **AndroidManifest.xml** the following line in the application section :

```
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/nameOfXmlFileYouCreated"
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are running in localhost you should use `http://10.0.2.2:8080/` as a base url, you need to specify the port, otherwise it won't work.